# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Пожалуйста помогите мне решить проблему, когда я закидываю в бота фотографию я получаю ошибку.

```
line 1583, in photo
elif status.startswith("communicate"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Вот сама строка на которую ссылается ошибка.

```
    elif status.startswith("communicate"):
    deal_id = int(status.split("__")[1])
    deal = db.get_deal(deal_id)
    if from_id != deal['seller'] and from_id != deal['buyer']:
        return
    if deal['status'] != "waiting_for_pay" and deal['status'] != "waiting_goods_transfer" or \
            deal['status'] == "arbitrage":
        return
    db.add_communicate_message(deal_id, "[[фото]]")
    if from_id == deal['seller']:
        receiver = deal['buyer']
    else:
        receiver = deal['seller']
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Перейти в режим переписки", callback_data=json.dumps(
        {"action": "communicate", "deal_id": deal_id})))
    app.send_photo(receiver, photo_id, caption=f"Новое сообщение в сделке #{deal_id}", reply_markup=kb)
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выйти из режима переписки",
                                      callback_data=json.dumps({"action": "exit_communicate"})))
    app.send_message(from_id, "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено второму участнику сделки", reply_markup=kb)
```

Сам бот работает отлично, только когда пользователь закинул картинку все он отлетает с ошибкой.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: Очевидно, в переменной `status` по какой-то причине оказывается значение `None`. Больше мы ничего не можем здесь сказать

Comment: А как мне исправить не знаете ? на видео и документы идет похожий код и все работает, а вот на картинке не работает.

Comment: Сделать так, чтобы в переменной `status` оказался какой-нибудь объект, у которого действительно будет существовать метод `startswith`. Так как мы не знаем, что вообще такое `status`, откуда оно берётся и зачем оно тут надо — больше мы здесь ничего прокомментировать не сможем

Comment: сейчас я весь код скину тут

Comment: Весь код скорее всего нарушит правила сайта, хороший вопрос должен содержать не весь код, а [mcve]